# Proxying an array type

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection, proxy-classes

I'm writing new TFS-related tasks in the MSBuild Community Task project.

How do I proxy an array type? The CheckIn function exposed in the TFS assembly expects an array of PendingChange objects i.e.: "PendingChange[]".

Now, I've proxied the PendingChange class, but how do I get the CheckIn method?

```
MethodInfo getPendEditMethod = _type.GetMethod("CheckIn", new Type[] { typeof(string[]), typeof(PendingChange[]) });
```

This will evidently not work.

Same thing, how do I invoke the method once I've gotten a handle to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question: `typeof(Array)` should do.
For your second question, look at [MethodInfo.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx).